# Unable to connect to Azure SQL database for creating an entity data model

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to create an entity data model using the wizard to an existing Azure SQL database. I get to the Choose Your Data Connection page of the wizard when we select new Connection It will open with an error:

> An unexpected error occurred in the .net framework data provider for MySQL please contact the provider vendor to resolve this problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error mentions MySQL, which I wouldn't expect for an Azure SQL connection

Comment: I also didn't understand why I got this error